# Accessing arbitrary list of symbols returned by getSymbols()?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Short version: How do I symbolically access objects returned by getSymbols()?

(I am learning R and this is to be my first 'real life' script/function. I have used the better part of the day searching and I am still bewildered).

**I want to take an arbitrary set of symbols and get the percentage return for each symbol from their high within the last year until now.**

(Or more generally, I want to do some manipulation on each symbol individually).

I have tried several approaches; storing them into a new.env() and trying to parse them there, and also putting them into a list(), but I still cannot access their $High.
I have still not learned lapply and eapply.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(quantmod)
symbols<-(c("^DJI", "^GDAXI", "^SPC","^RUT", "XOM", "K"))

t1<-as.POSIXlt(as.Date(Sys.Date()))
t1$year<-t1$year-1 #one year ago
start_date<-t1
for(i in symbols) {
  x<-getSymbols(i, from=start_date, auto.assign=FALSE)
  print(seriesHi(x))  #used for test only
# get the high value
# get the last value
# Print symbol name:
# Print last/high
}
```

I could probably do it with brute force, but I am looking for something elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you have date time object in your data frame, you can simply subset your date time object

```
#this uses a range of dates, but you can use date parts as well
your_subset <- subset(df, POSIXtime >= as.POSIXct('2015-02-07 13:45')
              POSIXtime <= Sys.time())
```

Then you can simple make a table of your data. It can be as simple as:

```
symbols<-c("^DJI", "^GDAXI", "^SPC","^RUT", "XOM", "K","XOM")

your_proportions <- table(symbols)
your_proportions / length(symbols)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the answer I'm looking for. It's not the subsetting of the date I'm after. It's the returned object from getSymbols(). Calling all getSymbols() and quantmod experts